# Remainder Question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

What process do I use to show what is the remainder when `14 × 7^36 + 92 when divided by 8`?

Is it the same to show the remainder of `5^2003 when divided by 7`?

I tried out the problem using congruent modulo but cannot help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

For the first $7^2=49\equiv1\pmod8\implies 7^{2n}\equiv1$ where $n$ is any integer $\ge0$

For the second $5^3=125\equiv-1\pmod7$ and $2003=667\cdot3+2$

$\displaystyle\implies 5^{2003}=(5^3)^{667}\cdot5^2\equiv(-1)^{667}\cdot5^2\pmod 7$

Comment: I understand the hint but I am not sure how to proceed.  As in the first one, 7^2n is always going to give us a remainder of 1 as long as n is over 0.  How do I use this information to finish the problem? IE multiplying it by 14 and adding 92.

Comment: I believe the answer to the first question is 5. Is this correct?

Comment: I also got 3 as the answer for the second question.

Comment: @user2461994,so, we have $7^{36}\equiv1\pmod8\implies 14\cdot7^{36}\equiv14\pmod8\equiv6$ and $\implies 14\cdot7^{36}+92\equiv6+92\pmod8\equiv2$  For the second, $(-1)^{667}\cdot5^2\equiv-25\pmod7\equiv-4\equiv3$

Answer (score 0):

We need to find out Rem [(14*7^36 + 92)/8] 
Let us break this into three smaller problems 
Rem [14/8] = 6 
Rem [7^36 / 8] = Rem [(-1)^36 / 8] = 1
Rem [92 / 8] = 4

So, we can say that
Rem [(14*7^36 + 92)/8] 
= Rem [(6*1 + 4) / 8] 
= **Rem [10/8] = 2**

Comment: Why are you answering this question with an accepted answer from 2013?

Comment: Thanks for your eagerness to answer questions.  Since this question already has a good answer your efforts would be more beneficial if you answered questions that do not already have good answers.  It will also help to familiarize yourself with mathjax to format your answers nicely.  A good tutorial is here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score -1):

**Divide individualy**
(14/8)*(7^36)/8+92/8.  ----(A)
$14/8==6.  ----(1)$
$(7^36)/8=[(8-1)^36]/8==[(-1)^36]/8==1. 
--(2)
$92/8==4. ----(3)$
$Now (1) (2) (3) put in (A)$
**[6*1+4]/8=10/8== >2 REMAINDER**

Comment: [mathjax references](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553)